# This template's simple email form isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been using a template to build a website recently and everything has been working great... except the email script variables are blank every time.

The form:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

The action (sendemail.php):

```
<?php
    $name      = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $from      = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject   = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message   = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
    $to        = 'info@website.org';

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$from.">"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: <".$from.">"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    die;
?>
```

The jQuery:

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Do you guys have any insights? I don't mess with jQuery, usually.

Comment: `mail()` requires a mail server to send emails. Perhaps PHPMailer is a better alternative. With it, you can actually verify if an email is send or not.

Comment: I just noticed that the `$headers` are an array. I believe that should be a string. Gonna fiddle with that. Might delete my question if this works.

Comment: Yeah, should be a string. `join('\r\n', $headers)` Also, it might be a good idea to check if any of the $_POST[] vars are empty. Robots might follow the link with empty post requests resulting in empty emails and maybe even add a captcha

Comment: Fixed the headers issue but despite filling out the form, `$_POST` is empty anyways. Manually filling out the name, from, subject, message, variables with strings in the sendemail.php works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP:

```
$headers = [ // or array( for older PHP versions. 
 "MIME-Version: 1.0",
 "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1",
 "From: $name <$from>",
 "Reply-To: <$from>",
 "Subject: $subject",
 "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()
];

mail($to, $subject, $message, join('\r\n', $headers));
```

For Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: {
      name: $('#name').val(),
      email: $('#email').val(),
      subject: $('#subject').val(),
      message: $('#message').val()
    },
}).done(function(data){
    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

For HTML

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Subject"></input>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Alright. A combination of things were wrong with my stuff. Here's what I did to fix all the issues. Feel free to edit your answer to reflect it. a) Added an input for the subject line. b) gave an `id=` to each input. c) Used `$('#name').val()` etc. Also, as a side note, `<input>` tags don't need to be closed, but for xhtml strictness they are self closing `<input />`

Comment: Alright, updated for your fix even though jquery `"input[name='name']"` can be valid. I would recommend updating it for HTML 5 because in my experience XHTML is not worth the effort. Updating from it is also a pain cause in any other html version `<input />` can result in unexpected behavior.